# Cannot install Angular Cli on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I have tried so many times in so many ways to install angular on my ubuntu laptop. but it says,

> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean` and then retry installing AngularCLI.

Comment: I don't know if this fits for you but this may help you: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/14#issuecomment-376055680

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with sudo:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```